# Adding a Winning Feature to the 'Ghost Game'

Tags: python

Recently I've been getting back into programming and decided to add a feature to the ghost game, you can see the original code below.

```
from random import randint
print('Ghost Game')
feeling_brave=True
score=0
while feeling_brave:
  ghost_door = randint(1, 3)
  print('Three doors ahead')
  print('A ghost behind one.')
  print('Which door do you open?')
  door = input('1, 2, or 3?')
  door_num = int(door)
  if door_num == ghost_door:
      print('GHOST!')
      feeling_brave = False
  else:
      print('No ghost!')
      print('Y0u enter the next room.')
      score = score + 1
print('Run Away!')
print('Game over! You scored', score)
```

Seeing as you can only lose in this game I figured I would add a way to win.

```
#Ghost Game
from random import randint
print('Ghost Game')
feeling_brave=True
score=0
while feeling_brave:
  ghost_door = randint(1, 3)
  print('Three doors ahead')
  print('A ghost behind one.')
  print('Which door do you open?')
  door = input('1, 2, or 3?')
  door_num = int(door)
  if door_num == ghost_door:
     print('GHOST!')
     feeling_brave = False
  else:
     print('No ghost!')
     print('You enter the next room.')
     score = score + 1
if score == 2:        
     print ('You Won!')
print('Run Away!')
print('Game over! You scored', score)
```

I understand the problem, the if else statement is a loop and if I used a break statement the lose ending plays too, along with the if score == 2 statement which still plays if the score is 2, however I want to break the loop and only print the you won statement,
Any tips would be appreciated (:

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code snippets with the tweaked if/else tests will produce the desired game scenario.

```
#Ghost Game
from random import randint
print('Ghost Game')

score=0
while True:                   # Just used "True" in lieu of a boolean variable
    ghost_door = randint(1, 3)
    print('Three doors ahead')
    print('A ghost behind one.')
    print('Which door do you open?')
    door = input('1, 2, or 3?')
    door_num = int(door)
    if door_num == ghost_door:
        print('GHOST! = Sorry, you lost')
        break
    else:
        print('No ghost!')
        score = score + 1
        if score == 2:
            print('You Won! - Run Away!')
            break
    print('You enter the next room.')

print('Game over! You scored', score)
```

I shuffled a couple of bits around to increment the score and test for a win.  Following are some sample games played.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Ghost$ python3 Ghost.py 
Ghost Game
Three doors ahead
A ghost behind one.
Which door do you open?
1, 2, or 3?1
No ghost!
You enter the next room.
Three doors ahead
A ghost behind one.
Which door do you open?
1, 2, or 3?2
No ghost!
You Won! - Run Away!
Game over! You scored 2

@Una:~/Python_Programs/Ghost$ python3 Ghost.py 
Ghost Game
Three doors ahead
A ghost behind one.
Which door do you open?
1, 2, or 3?1
GHOST! = Sorry, you lost
Game over! You scored 0
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Thank you, that helped so much and solved a lot of problems I was having when it comes to correctly indenting my code to get my desired effects!